# Change the DHCP range for LXC without changing physical interfaces

Tags: networking, dhcp, lxc

I am trying to change the DHCP range of my LXC containers. By default , ow addresses given by the dhcp are **10.0.3.X**. how can I change this range so my containers can have IP in the range **10.0.2.X**.
**PS: I want to keep my interfaces unchanged (I don't want to change the file /etc/network/interfaces).**

Comment: You will have to change the address range to be assigned on the DHCP server, AND take down and bring up each interface.

Answer (score 2):

LXC assigns an internal set of IPs within the range of 10.0.3.2 to 10.0.3.254 which is defined in `/etc/default/lxc-net`.

Modify

```
LXC_DHCP_RANGE=
LXC_DHCP_MAX=
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember exactly which "how-to" it is covered in but Flockport's various LXC guides are pretty good for reference info.

https://www.flockport.com/guides/